# How do I release the value I want to return?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I know this is fairly fundamental stuff.

I have a class with a function that returns the name of the month; I'm not sure how to release a value that I want to return to prevent leaks.

In the class this value is declared:

```
static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
if (formatter == nil) {
    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM yyyy"];
}
```

Things happen, and then:

```
if([exampleDate isEqualToDate:
    [[self creationDate] laterDate:exampleDate]])
{ //earlierDate returns the earlier date
    return(@"Examples");
}else{
    return([formatter stringFromDate:[self creationDate]]);
}
```

I've tried using autorelease but I'm using it incorrectly because I get a crash when I try to release it. I've also tried assigning the return value to a string, but I have the same crashing problems. Sorry for asking a question that is so fundamental, but I'd appreciate knowing how to release this properly, while still returning the value - and understanding how it works.

Comment: It's definitely what autorelease is made for. How are you using autorelease when it crashes?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are not switching to ARC? This question would be irrelevant then :)

Comment: For the example approve  formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

Comment: @dasblinkenlight because there are a lot of classes that don't convert nicely to ARC - I'm not ready to go there quite yet. Next time I start a new project though....

Comment: Are you asking when to release the formatter or the return value of your function?

Comment: Seems that it's a shared instance so you may want to release it in an __attribute__((destructor)) function or in +unload.

Comment: @H2CO3 what would that look like?

Comment: declare your shared instance as a global variable, then use a destructor something like `__attribute__((destructor)) void finalize() { [formatter release]; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no leaks in the return part. Since `stringFromDate:` is not `copy`, `mutableCopy`, `retain`, `alloc` or `new` it returns already an autoreleased object.

Your `NSDateFormatter` will leak when the class is deallocated. If you don't want it to leak you should create a `@property` for it and release it in dealloc.
Local static objects will always leak.
I would not use such objects outside of singletons. Each time you create one of your classes you will leak an NSDateFormatter. Using `@property` is better in almost every case.

I've seen hacks like this but in my opinion they solve a problem you shouldn't have in the first place:

```
- (NSString *)someDateFromString:(NSString *)str {
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (formatter == nil) {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    }
    if (str == nil) {
        [formatter release];
        formatter = nil;
        return nil;
    }
    // do something
    return date;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self someDateFromString:nil]; // will release the static date formatter.
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: But when does formatter disappear/release? My (understandably flawed) understanding is that if you alloc you need to release.

Comment: if you want to release it don't create a static variable for it. create a @property for it and release it in dealloc.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. The class hasn't got a dealloc function yet because I haven't needed one. I'll add @property and dealloc tmrw and let you know how I get on.